# deploy ember app to azure w/o cli

Tags: node.js, azure, ember.js

I have an existing Ember application that I did not write (I know nothing about Ember or Node), and I need to deploy it to Azure.  Every article I've seen so far assumes that the reader has actual development knowledge of Ember and Node, and I don't have the time to learn all of that before deploying this application.  Can anyone give me some simple, basic steps on how to deploy the application to Azure?  And I would prefer to not install and use a cli -- I'm hoping I can just ftp the files and make a few adjustments in the Azure management portal. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, it doesn't look like there's a simple FTP way to deploy an existing Ember application to Azure.  I was finally able to make some progress by having the application in a Git repository, setting up an application environment in Azure, and then using that environment's console to run some of the commands I found at these links:

http://www.felixrieseberg.com/deploying-ember-cli-to-azure-websites/

https://github.com/felixrieseberg/ember-cli-azure-deploy

http://ember-cli.com/user-guide/

I was able to install Ember and connect the Azure environment to my Github repository.  I've verified that the files are all deploying correctly.  I'm still having a separate issue, but I think it's related to my specific code, not the cli installation commands.  Hope this is helpful to someone down the road.